# JQGrid, Image Drop Down Box in toolbar search MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, drop-down-menu

I have a JQgrid with the toolbar search. Currently I've mapped the DropDownList for the search of a column with a partial view which will provide the html for the drop down.
What I would like to do is instead of a standard DropDown I would like to have an Image DropDownList in the toolbar searching of JQGrid.
Is there a way to do that in JQuery or anything else which will work with IE and to keep the current implementation of calling a partial view?

Thanks in advance for your help